# Fasm и Masm проблема в понимании

Tags: ассемблер

У меня возникла проблема, я купил книгу Калашникова по ассемблеру, выглядит новой, но разработка ведётся под dos. И вот было решено написать hello world и столкнулся с проблемой.Masm  устарел, fasm на него не похож. Как быть? Я слышал про использование каких-то макросов. Для меня человека,который только перешёл с python тяжело понять особенно при таких различиях даже в компиляторах.Спасибо.

Comment: masm32 отлично работает под windows и даже виндовые приложения может собирать. но конечно все общение с внешнем миром надо делать не так как в DOS

Comment: Ну или ставить эмулятор и пользоваться DOS, что бы понять основы хватит. а потом уже изучать работу с более современными ОС, когда само железо будете понимать

Comment: Для начинающих, чтобы и по dos, и по windows я бы посоветовал (скачать) книги Крупника А.Б. по ассемблеру. В них примеры для masm. В продаже, насколько я знаю, их сейчас нет, поэтому только скачать.